# Nginx blocking Wordpress plugin update

Tags: nginx, wordpress

Nginx seems to be blocking the update of some plugins like revisionary (used to do so with translatepress too but didn't the last time) by locking some strange files inside the plugins directory. The plugin can only be updates/removed after restarting nginx since even from shell as root it blocks the removal of plugin forlders. For example:

```
root@www:~# rm -r /var/www/wordpress/fsmuw/wp-content/plugins/revisionary/
rm: das Entfernen von '/var/www/wordpress/fsmuw/wp-content/plugins/revisionary/admin/.nfs0000000000229dc300000041' ist nicht möglich: Das Gerät oder die Ressource ist belegt
rm: das Entfernen von '/var/www/wordpress/fsmuw/wp-content/plugins/revisionary/admin/.nfs0000000000229dc400000042' ist nicht möglich: Das Gerät oder die Ressource ist belegt
rm: das Entfernen von '/var/www/wordpress/fsmuw/wp-content/plugins/revisionary/common/css/.nfs0000000000229dd600000043' ist nicht möglich: Das Gerät oder die Ressource ist belegt
rm: das Entfernen von '/var/www/wordpress/fsmuw/wp-content/plugins/revisionary/vendor/publishpress/wordpress-version-notices/assets/css/.nfs0000000000229e2600000044' ist nicht möglich: Das Gerät oder die Ressource ist belegt
```

The error message transalted to english would be something like "the removal of [...] is not possible: device or ressource is in use".
This only happens with very few plugins and it can be resolved by restarting Nginx, yet it's still a bit annoying. Has anyone any idea why that is and what to change so these plugins can be updated automatically?

Using Nginx 1.20.0 on Debian 10.9

Comment: It doesn't seem to do much with NGINX, but rather the fact that you are hosting your WordPress on a NFS mount point. See [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/what-are-nfs-files-accumulate-and-why-cant-they-be-deleted-even-after-stopping-cognos-8) for details. For performance reasons, I highly recommend against putting WordPress files on NFS share, and anything that isn't local to the server where PHP-FPM/NGINX is.

Comment: Thanks for that tip. Since we have no performance issues and have a reason to have the directories mounted as nfs I'll see if I can use the tip from the IBM site to have a cronjob to regularly clean up those files. Maybe I even find a way to include it in the update process but I doubt that since I don't think that wordpress has high enough privileges